# Display Raster Layer using ArcGIS Javascript API

Tags: javascript, raster, arcgis

I Want to display a raster layer on to my page using ArcGIS JavaScript API.
Loading Feature layer is easy and pretty forward but the raster layer is giving me hard time.

Here is the the MapService: http://ags.servirlabs.net/ArcGIS/rest/services/ReferenceNode/TRMM_30DAY/MapServer/0
which is Raster layer.

Do you have any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add raster layers to your map using the ArcGISTiledMapService layer, for example:

```
// assuming 'map' is a reference to your map
map.addLayer(new esri.layers.ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer("http://ags.servirlabs.net/ArcGIS/rest/services/ReferenceNode/TRMM_30DAY/MapServer"));
```

There are some good examples on the ArcGIS JavaScript API site here:

https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/#tiled_layers

One thing to be aware of with tiled layers is that you can only add tiled layers to your map if they are using the same spatial reference.  You can't add a layer as a tiled layer with a different spatial reference as it's cache of tiles have already been produced using it's spatial reference.  You can add a layer as a Dynamic layer to re-project it.

Comment: Thank you Simon for your quick reply, but you approach doesnt work for me. Here I used the link you provided and replace the MapService url to my url and hosted on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4DCjL/2/). The rasterlayer does not show up :(

Comment: I'd suggest copy one of the tiled samples from the ESRI site I linked to, for example, this one: https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/layers_ags_tiled.html .  Create a new page and paste the code as is.  Run it and it should work.  Then, replace only the URL to the esri tiled layer with your URL.  It should then work and if it doesn't, it suggests a problem with the service.  Assuming it does work, look at the code on that page (it's only a few lines) and make sure you transfer it to your project.  Make sure you get the require statement correct to load the modules.

Comment: That is exactly what I did copied and pasted the sample code and replace the service url, but no luck. Finally I was able to make this work via the **DynamicLayer** -> Only DynamicLayer would let me render raster layer, thanks to you for mentioning it in your earlier answer. And another dude in the forum also suggested I use  **ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer** which works perfectly as seen here on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JSkinn3/KmrGd/)

Answer (score 1):

How you add a map service layer depends on whether or not the service is cached. Look at http://ags.servirlabs.net/ArcGIS/rest/services/ReferenceNode/TRMM_30DAY/MapServer in a browser and see the following:

**Single Fused Map Cache**: false

Because it's not cached, you must use [`ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html), not [`ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/arcgistiledmapservicelayer-amd.html). If it were cached, you could use either one.

```
map.addLayer(new esri.layers.ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(
    "http://ags.servirlabs.net/ArcGIS/rest/services/ReferenceNode/TRMM_30DAY/MapServer"));
```

Note that if you had a service with multiple layers in it and you wanted to display only a subset of them, you would create an `ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer` and then use its [`setVisibleLayers`](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/arcgisdynamicmapservicelayer-amd.html#setvisiblelayers) method to set which layers should be visible. In this case, you don't need to worry about it, because your map has only one layer in it.